# Why cant i call objects from a json file in p5js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, javascript-objects

Ive been working on a school project, and for this game i need to call objects to create a level. However, whenever i call the info of the objects, it always ends it with an undefined, and wont produce anything.

the JSON file reads:

```
[
  {
    "x": 200,
    "y": 100,
    "l": 100,
    "w": 100,
    "wallColor": "black",
    "hit": true
  },
  {
    "x": 200,
    "y": 200,
    "l": 100,
    "w": 100,
    "wallColor": "black",
    "hit": false
  },
  {
    "x": 200,
    "y": 300,
    "l": 100,
    "w": 100,
    "wallColor": "black",
    "hit": false
  },
  {
    "x": 200,
    "y": 400,
    "l": 100,
    "w": 100,
    "wallColor": "black",
    "hit": false
  },
  {
    "x": 200,
    "y": 500,
    "l": 100,
    "w": 100,
    "wallColor": "black",
    "hit": false
  },
  {
    "x": 200,
    "y": 600,
    "l": 100,
    "w": 100,
    "wallColor": "black",
    "hit": false
  },
  {
    "x": 200,
    "y": 700,
    "l": 100,
    "w": 100,
    "wallColor": "black",
    "hit": false
  },
  {
    "x": 200,
    "y": 800,
    "l": 100,
    "w": 100,
    "wallColor": "black",
    "hit": false
  },
  {
    "x": 500,
    "y": 100,
    "l": 100,
    "w": 100,
    "wallColor": "black",
    "hit": false
  },
  {
    "x": 500,
    "y": 200,
    "l": 100,
    "w": 100,
    "wallColor": "black",
    "hit": false
  },
  {
    "x": 500,
    "y": 300,
    "l": 100,
    "w": 100,
    "wallColor": "black",
    "hit": false
  },
  {
    "x": 500,
    "y": 400,
    "l": 100,
    "w": 100,
    "wallColor": "black",
    "hit": false
  },
  {
    "x": 500,
    "y": 500,
    "l": 100,
    "w": 100,
    "wallColor": "black",
    "hit": false
  },
  {
    "x": 500,
    "y": 600,
    "l": 100,
    "w": 100,
    "wallColor": "black",
    "hit": false
  },
  {
    "x": 500,
    "y": 700,
    "l": 100,
    "w": 100,
    "wallColor": "black",
    "hit": false
  },
  {
    "x": 500,
    "y": 800,
    "l": 100,
    "w": 100,
    "wallColor": "black",
    "hit": false
  }
]
```

and the code to call the info and put them in an array with their objects, reads:

```
  wallArray0 = level1; //level1 is the JSON file
  wallArray = [];
  for(let protowall in wallArray0){
    let testwall = new Wall(wallArray0[protowall].x, wallArray0[protowall].y);
    wallArray.push(testwall);
  }
```

Comment: How do you load the JSON file? How is the JSON parsed into JS?

Answer (score 1):

Because `protowall` is not an index but the element itself. So you shouldn't try to reference `wallArray0[protowall].x`, but simply `protowall.x`.

Also for arrays you should be using a for..of loop instead of a for..in loop.

In other words try this:

```js
for(const protowall of wallArray0){
    const testwall = new Wall(protowall.x, protowall.y);
    wallArray.push(testwall);
}
```

A more elegant solution would be

```
const wallArray = wallArray0.map(protowall => new Wall(protowall.x, protowall.y));
```

Comment: Ive tried calling just protowall, but it results in the same outcome. Also, changing the in to of makes wallArray0 no longer iterable.

Comment: In that case I suspect you're not parsing the JSON properly and wallArray0 holds a string instead of an array. Try running JSON.parse() on your JSON string.